# image not getting displaying with img tag in lotus notes?

Tags: html, lotus-notes, email-client, inline-images

i have my email body consisting below URL

```
   <img src="http://10.210.162.79:8000/web/getImage.do?actionCode=2&imageId=1008"/>
```

but image is not displayed(it displayed as cross icon). I also tried below setting

LotusNotes-Preferences-Mail-Internet-Image Security--Uncheck To ensure privacy do not show remote images without my permission

Same thing works on my collegue system but for me  it sill does not display image> Not sure what i am missing here?
I have already tried restarting of lotus notes. My lotus notes version is 8.5.

Comment: Well the first thing that stands out is "287" is not a valid number. Has to go from 0-255. Also 800 is not a normal port for web traffic (doesn't mean it is wrong, just should be 80 normally).

Comment: @simon please ignore the ip. I just use some arbitrary number for my post. Corrected it

Comment: Duplicate question on SuperUser.com. I suggest you close this one and have people help you on SuperUser.com: http://superuser.com/questions/577483/lotus-notes-does-not-display-the-image-with-img-tag-in-body

Comment: What happens if you try to bring up the image http://10.210.162.79:8000/web/getImage.do?actionCode=2&imageId=1008 in a browser running on your own computer?

Comment: @Richard i can see that image from browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a mail that was sent to both you and your colleague, then my best guess is that the two of you have different settings for your inbound mail. If your copy of the message is going through a format conversion on the server, it's possible that the firewall is blocking the HTTP image retrieval on the server.  If your colleague's copy is not going through the same conversion on the server, then it would be his own computer that is retrieving the image and the firewall is allowing it.

So...  Check your Person document in the Domino Directory and look at the setting **Format preference for incoming mail**.  (It's on the right side of the Basics tab.)  If it is set to Prefers **Notes Rich Text**, and your colleague's Person documentis set to either **Prefer MIME** or **Keep in senders format**, then that's the most likely answer.

Comment: Its Prefer MIME for both of us

Comment: Okay, in that case it's not a difference in these settings.  I guess I would still double-check that the message was delivered to you in MIME format. I.e., look at the fields list in the Document Properties dialog, scroll down to the Body item(s) and see if the Data Type is shown as "Rich Text" or as "MIME Part".  If it is a MIME Part, then the only other thing I can think of is to compare your Location document with your colleagues' Location document, and see if you have different proxy settings.

Answer (score 2):

By default the image access should be disabled.  You have to enable it to see the image by default download

Open Lotus notes >> Preference >> Mail >> Internet >> Image security

uncheck the check box if it is checked already..

Answer (score 0):

Edit `notes.ini` and make sure these two parameters are set:

`ShowMIMEImagesAsAttachments=0`

`BrowserRenderDisable=0`